# NavigationBar back button change text after popViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` connected to a `UITabBarCotnroller`.
When i push a `ViewController` and in that class i write this code in their `viewWillAppear` method

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "Back.png")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "";
```

By this code i am just setting a back button image with empty title.
But when i push another screen over the current pushed screen and then tap back it again shows the title with text "Back"
I am writing the above code in every view controller's `viewWillAppear` method which will be push.

Comment: You can try changing the title like that: `NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem ("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);`. This is Xamarin C# code, but it should be really easy to convert it to Swift.

Comment: showing back in title is the only problem you facing?

Comment: YES, Back title is the only problem @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I believe setting the `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` will work in `viewDidAppear()`, I found issues with setting the back text itself. I always had to set the text with a new button, and even then, it worked better for me to do it from the transitioning controller (as that's the view they would go back to, so I didn't have to care where the user was transitioning from).

You can try using this in your `viewWillAppear()`, but I'm using this in my `prepare(for:, sender:)` function.

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "" // In my case, I was setting it here; you would blank it out
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```